# Find dialog, SHIFT+ENTER to search in other direction?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, in contrast to most other editors, I cannot use SHIFT+ENTER in the find dialog to search in the different direction (prominently used, to go back to the previous find position).

Is there a different shortcut? Any option I can set to enable this behavior?

Comment: Change "Direction" to "Up"

Comment: Unfortunately, this is 5 tabs or a mouse click away, too much to work efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 7.3.3 you can now press SHIFT+ENTER like you are used to :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Shft-F3` to find previous in Notepad++
 For more
[Click Here](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm)
If the Find dialog is open just use `UP`

Comment: Does not work if the find dialog is open.

Comment: Try Ctrl-Shft-F3

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+F3 doesn't work either. "If the find dialog is open just use up" -> no, 5 tabs or even worse: a mouse click away. Too much work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for incremental search and there you can *immediately* use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to move through found occurrences while still keeping main *Find* dialog capability: typing text you want to search.